# Backends are not healthy in GKE cluster with Istio and Cloud Armor

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, istio-gateway, google-cloud-armor

I'm trying to play with [Cloud Armor Adaptive protection](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/adaptive-protection-overview) in front of a GKE cluster. I found [this guide from contino-engineering](https://medium.com/contino-engineering/configuring-ddos-protection-with-google-cloud-armor-for-your-gke-provisioned-istio-ingressgateway-a9e862dc1683) and this one from [always up always on](https://alwaysupalwayson.com/posts/2021/04/cloud-armor/). However, both of those use a simple hello world example and I'm trying to deploy a (hopefully?) more realistic deployment by using the [bookinfo](https://github.com/istio/istio/tree/master/samples/bookinfo) example from istio. (I have similar results using the [onlineboutique](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/microservices-demo) as well.)

The issue is that the backends never get healthy. I'm assuming it is because the health checkers can't reach the health check service, but I'm new to all this and unsure how to verify.

This is my TF for deploying the cluster. Note that the [`ip_allocation_policy`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster#ip_allocation_policy) is equivalent to the `--enable-ip-aliases` gcloud parameter... I think. I'm not enabling CloudRun here in the hopes of simplifying things.

cluster tf

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  provider = google-beta
  name     = "my-gke-cluster"
  location = "us-central1"

  # We can't create a cluster with no node pool defined, but we want to only use
  # separately managed node pools. So we create the smallest possible default
  # node pool and immediately delete it.
  remove_default_node_pool = true
  initial_node_count       = 4

  networking_mode = "VPC_NATIVE"
  ip_allocation_policy {
    // Set to blank to have a range chosen with the default size
    cluster_ipv4_cidr_block = ""
  }

  addons_config {
    istio_config {
      disabled = false
      auth = "AUTH_MUTUAL_TLS"
    }
  }
}
```

After getting creds, I apply my backendconfig to allow(?)/enable(?) the health check.

```sh
cat <<EOF > /tmp/backendconfig.yaml
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: my-backendconfig
spec:
  healthCheck:
    requestPath: /healthz/ready
    port: 15021
    type: HTTP
  securityPolicy:
    name: my-security-policy
EOF

kubectl apply -n istio-system -f /tmp/backendconfig.yaml
```

Then I patch the ingressgateway:

```sh
cat <<EOF > /tmp/patch.yaml
spec:
   type: NodePort
metadata:
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "my-backendconfig"}'
status: null
EOF
kubectl patch svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system --patch-file /tmp/patch.yaml
```

Finally, apply the ingress resource

```sh
cat <<EOF > /tmp/istio-ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: istio-ingressgateway
                port: 
                  number: 80
EOF

kubectl apply -n istio-system -f /tmp/istio-ingress.yaml
```

Rollout new pods for good measure:

```sh
kubectl rollout restart deploy -n istio-system
```

After waiting 10+ minutes, I see the new load balancer in the Google console showing the unhealthy backend:
[image: Load balancer]

Comment: You need to manually enable firewall rule to allow http LB IP range to pass health check as the health checks aren't exposed through ingress.
[This Github resource](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/cluster-loadbalancing/glbc#prerequisites) will help.

Answer (score 0):

@Anant Swaraj
I tracked this down to a mismatched port for my `VirtualService`:

```yaml
# ---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: health
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - bookinfo-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - headers:
        user-agent:
          prefix: GoogleHC
      method:
        exact: GET
      uri:
        exact: /
    rewrite:
      authority: istio-ingressgateway:15020
      uri: /healthz/ready
    route:
      - destination:
          host: istio-ingressgateway
          port:
            number: 15020
```

I used 15020 there, but 15021 in my `BackendConfig`. Not really sure where I got either after looking at so many posts so many times.

But as @Anant Swaraj mentions, there will need to be a firewall rule in addition.